# Docker good practices. "data" in a volume vs image

Tags: docker

I currently have an application that (for the sake of simplicity) just requires a `.csv` file. However, this file needs to be constructed with a script, let's call it `create_db.py`.

I have two images (let's call them API1 and API2) that require the `.csv` file so I declared a 2-stage build and both images copy the `.csv` into their filesystem. This makes the Dockerfiles somewhat ugly as API1 and API2 have the **same** first lines of the Dockerfile plus there is no guarantee that both images have the same `.csv` because it is constructed "on the fly"

I have two possible solutions to this problem:

First option:

- Make a separate docker image that executes `create_db.py` and then tag it as `data:latest`. Copy the `.csv` in API1 and API2 doing

```
FROM data:latest as datapipeline
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.7.12
...
...

COPY --from=datapipeline file.csv .
```

Then I will need to create a bash file to make sure `data:latest` is built (and up to date) before building API1 and API2.

**Pros**: Data can be pulled from a repository if you are in a different machine, no need to "rebuilt it" again.

**Cons**: Every time I build API1 and API2 I need to make sure that `data:latest` is up to date. API1 and API2 require `data:latest` to be used.

Second option:

- Create a volume `data/` and an image that runs `create_db.py` and mount the volume so the `.csv` is in `data/`. Then mount the volume for API1 and API2. I will also need some kind of mechanism that makes sure that `data/` contains the required file.

Mounting volumes sounds like the right choice when dealing with shared data, but in this case, I am not sure because my data needs "to be built" before being able to be used. Should I go with the first option then?

---

**Chosen solution, thanks to @David Maze**

What I ended up doing is separating the data pipeline in its own Docker image and then COPY from that image in API1 and API2.

To make sure that API1 and API2 always have the latest "data image" versión, the data pipeline calculate the hashes of all output files, then tries to do `docker pull data:<HASH>` if it fails it means that this version of the data is not in the registry and the data image is tagged as both `data:<HASH>` and `data:latest` and pushed to the registry. This guarantees that `data:latest` always points to the last data pushed to the registry and at the same time I can keep track of all the `data:<HASH>` versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it’s manageable size-wise, I’d prefer baking it into the image.  There’s two big reasons for this: it makes it possible to just `docker run` the image without any external host dependencies, and it works much better in cluster environments (Docker Swarm, Kubernetes) where sharing files can be problematic.

There’s two more changes you can make to this to improve your proposed Dockerfile.  You can pass the specific version of the dataset you’re using as an `ARG`, which will help the situation where you need to build two copies of the image and need them to have the same dataset.  You can also directly `COPY --from=` an image, without needing to declare it as a stage.

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.7.12
ARG data_version=latest
COPY --from=data:${data_version} file.csv .
```

I’d consider the volume approach only if the data file is really big (gigabytes).  Docker images start to get unwieldy at that size, so if you have a well-defined auxiliary data set you can break out, that will help things run better.  Another workable approach could be to store the datafile somewhere remote like an AWS S3 bucket, and download it at startup time (adds some risk of startup-time failure and increases the startup time, but leaves the image able to start autonomously).

Comment: I'm imagining a Makefile that will build "data" image and APPS images. Is there any mechanism to check if the data has changed and build and tag the image in that case or will I need to code that? for example with a md5 hash?

Comment: Nice answer! +1; regarding @GonzaloHernandez's latest question you may want to use the `docker build --pull` option [(see doc)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) that "always attempt to pull a newer version of the image" from the implied Docker registry (and this works for both `FROM …` and `COPY --from=…` directives).